# How to extract specific characters from a string that can vary

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to extract the specific part of the name of the file that can have varying number of '_'. I previously used partition/rpartition to strip everything before and after underscore bars, but I didn't take into account the possibilities of different underscore bar numbers.

The purpose of the code is to extract specific characters in between underscore bars.

```
filename = os.path.basename(files).partition('_')[2].rpartition('_')[0].rpartition('_')[0].rpartition('_')[0]
```

The above is my current code. A typical name of the file looks like:

```
P0_G12_190325184517_t20190325_5
```

or it can also have

```
P0_G12_190325184517_5
```

From what I understand, my current code's rpartition needs to match the number of underscore bars of the file for the first file, but the same code doesn't work for the second file obviously.

I want to extract

```
G12
```

this part can also be just two characters like G1 so two to three characters from the above types of filenames.

Comment: What about `os.path.basename(files).split('_')[1]`?

Comment: Does the position of GXX vary? If so, how about `re.findall('G\d+', files)`?

Comment: Oh.... didn't think about split. Split works perfectly thank you

Comment: @BongKyoSeo let me add it as the answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
os.path.basename(files).split('_')[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use `split` to create a list with the separate parts, like this:

```
files.split('_')
```

Or you could use regex:

https://regex101.com/r/jiUNLV/1

And do like this:

```
import re
pattern = r'.*_(\w{2,3})_\d+.*'

match = re.match(pattern, files)

if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```